# Made a function but it ignores my optional True/False statement

Tags: python, function, if-statement, boolean, fibonacci

So, I was just making a fibonacci function to return a printed version of the sequence and the variation, but it seems to be ignoring the 'if' statement and jumping to the "else". Don't have a clue of what could be happening here...

```
def fibonacci(r, var=False):
if var is True:
    n1 = 0
    n2 = 1
    for c in range(0, r):
        n3 = n1 + n2
        v = n3 / n2
        n1 = n2
        n2 = n3
        print(f'{v}', end=' ')
else:
    n1 = -1
    n2 = 1
    for c in range(0, r):
        n3 = n1 + n2
        n1 = n2
        n2 = n3
        print(f'{n3}', end=' ')


fibonacci((20, True))
```

Comment: `fibonacci((20, True))` calls the function with a tuple as argument for `r` and `var` with the default value

Comment: In Python, `(x, y, ...)` is the syntax for constructing a [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuple). So when you use two parens in `fibonacci((` you are creating a tuple and then calling a function on the created tuple. Like:  `fibonacci(   tuple(20, True)   )`. You need to drop one set of parens. (And read up on tuples, because they're cool!)

Answer (score 1):

Just call it like this:

```
fibonacci(20, True)
```

Then it will work. Otherwise you are giving a tuple to the function as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

you're passing in a tuple. Try calling:
fibonacci(20, True)

instead of calling:
fibonacci((20, True))

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you function content is outside from scope. Try to indent the function body to make it be part of function scope, like this:

```
def fibonacci(r, var=False):
    if var is True:
        n1 = 0
        n2 = 1
        for c in range(0, r):
            n3 = n1 + n2
            v = n3 / n2
            n1 = n2
            n2 = n3
            print(f'{v}', end=' ')
    else:
        n1 = -1
        n2 = 1
        for c in range(0, r):
            n3 = n1 + n2
            n1 = n2
            n2 = n3
            print(f'{n3}', end=' ')
```

Annnnnd... You're calling the function using a tuple, thats recognized as one value. Try to remove one parenthesis instance. Like this:

```
fibonacci(20, True)
```